# How to implement <Grid> in Universal Windows Platform App?

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, uwp

How to use **Gird** in Windows Apps?

> I want to create a Login form. I have used grid and used     but the Rows are not aligned properly, How can I do that?
>
> `<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
>           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
>               <ColumnDefinition Width="67*"/>
>               <ColumnDefinition Width="293*"/>
>           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
>           <StackPanel>
>               <TextBlock Text="Name" Height="32" Margin="0,0,0.333,0"  ></TextBlock>
>               <TextBlock Text="Last Name" Height="30" Margin="0,0,0.333,0" ></TextBlock>
>               <TextBlock Text="Address"></TextBlock>
>           </StackPanel>
>           <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
>               <TextBox></TextBox>
>               <TextBox></TextBox>
>               <TextBox></TextBox>
>           </StackPanel>
>       </Grid>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define the rows and columns in Grid.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="67*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="293*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Name" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="Last Name" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="Address" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>

    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="30"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="30"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="30"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for, It works Thank you Jefferey